# How to use Mysql FULLTEXT in multiple field

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I have to matching text in many field.Currently I have used Like in query.But Like give too many result.I have read about mysql FULLTEXT query and I have tried to apply in my query.But I don't know its working or not.

**Old query:**

```
select * from table where field1 like 'search text' or field2 like 'search text'
```

**Fulltext query :**

```
select * from table where MATCH(field1, field2) AGAINST ('search text' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE )
```

My question is that,It is possible search in all fields with or condition using Fulltext match query ?

Comment: FULTEXT is intended for large chunks of text. It sounds to me like you would want to explore the arcane world of regular expressions.

Comment: Also, FULLTEXT searching will simply be faster than LIKE, and may possibly allow for better ranking. It will not return fewer results -- that would imply that it was leaving stuff out.

Answer (score 1):

By default, mysql will search in both fields `MATCH(field1, field2)` like your old query.

All what you need is to create the fulltextindex for both fields.

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX index_name
    ON tbl_name (field1, field2);
```

For Example:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE MATCH(field1, field2) AGAINST ('word1 word2' IN BOOLEAN MODE );
```

You will find the same like:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name 
WHERE field1 LIKE '%word1%' OR field2 LIKE '%word1%' OR
      field1 LIKE '%word2%' OR field2 LIKE '%word2%'
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.Is it possible to search multiple string in Match query

Comment: yes in boolean mode you can use operators inside the searchstring like SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('+MySQL -YourSQL' IN BOOLEAN MODE); Doku: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/fulltext-boolean.html

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
where
name = 'search_key'
OR firstname ='search_key' 
OR lastname ='search_key'
```

may it will reach your question

Comment: I does not want like this.I have already used Like in query and its give too many result.

Comment: that means you want the query using multiple 'or' conditions..??

Comment: I want to get only specific result of search

Comment: User enter any string from search.So I have match this string from many fields.As per your edit, its match same string in fields But I want to search like a wild card and get specific result